# Wires entering the Breaker Box

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

Why do the two large wires go into a 40 amp double pole breaker and the small wire go into a single pole 30 amp breaker?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture would really help here, as would the make and model of your heat pump.

Comment: @ Daniel Griscom I've edited the title of my question because I had just realized that those wires I was referring too weren't associated with the heat & ac system after all. But I'm still curious as to why those wires are lugged in the way they are.

Comment: Can you post some photos please? This sounds...weird.

Comment: Without more info, the answer is simple: "Who knows?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double Pole Breakers use two hots ( 240v) AC, Electric Hot Water Tank, Stove, Dryer...
Single Pole Beakers use one hot (120v) lights, switches, outlets

Comment: This, of course, only applies in places like the US and Canada that use 120/240V split-phase.